# Batch Automation: Is there a way to change the image quality, when saving for web?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I have just downloaded the `/uploads/` folder, from a website I am working on.  This `/uploads/` folder, containing all uploaded images.

There are over 5,000 images, each not having been optimised for the web.  As such, I would like to use Photoshop to perform the following optimisations:

- Reduce Image Size;
- Change File Format to JPEG;
- Select 'Save for Web'.

I would like to automate this process than manually perform each Action.  I have tried the **Automate > Batch** approach.  Whilst this does perform the necessary actions, it does select the 'Low' option for image quality.  Is there anyway I could perform this Batch Action but with changing the 'Low' option to 'High'?

**Current Effort**

After some guidance, I have tried the below steps.  Unfortunately, I still cannot seem to achieve the results I am looking for ...

1. Select `New  Action` and name it accordingly;
2. Select the `Record` Button;
3. I then proceed to select `Open ...` then select the required image;
4. I then head to `File > Save for web`;
5. After I have made my modifications, I then select `Save` within the `Save for web` pop up window and save accordingly;
6. I then close the image.  When I close the image, I do not select the 'Save' feature since I have already Saved, when saving for web;
7. I then select `Stop Recording`;
8. I then head to `Automate > Batch` and enter the following settings:

[image]

I just cannot seem to get the images to save within the Destination Folder.  I have played around with the Settings.  For example:  Selecting and Deselecting the `Override Action "Save As" Commands` but the closest I can get is the images are simply being saved to the Desktop rather than the Destination Folder.

**Update**

I have managed to get the images to save within the Destination Folder.  The way I achieved this, was that I figured that when you Save for Web, you need to select `Save` and then `Cancel` when the save box appears.  Otherwise, the Action will save to that destination, regardless of what you enter into the Batch Settings.  That said, however, this approach triggers the following settings after each image:

[image]

I selected the `Override Action "Save As" Commands` but this just resulted in the images not being saved at all.

How can I include this within the Automation, so that I do not need to select the relevant options after each image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an **Action** with the steps exactly as you want them to be played and then make a **Batch** selecting this action from the **Batch Options Window**.

**Action**

[image: Action]

**Batch**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Definitely, what I was looking for.  That said, I cannot seem to get the Automation to actually save to the Destination Folder.  Whilst the Automation is in progress, a temporary file mometarily appears but then disappears.  The file I used, when recording the Action, is saved; so it is not as if I forgot to record the saving.  Any ideas?

Comment: Choose a destination folder different than the original one and don't add any save or save as command.

Comment: As the action has the option to export for web, try to make the batch activating **Override Action "Save as Commands"...**

Comment: I can seem to create the Action fine, for other modifications.  It just seems to be when I try to 'Save for Web'.  I will modify my question, to display screenshots of each step I am doing.

Comment: I have managed to get a bit of progress but wondering how to include the 'JPEG Options' box within the Automation.